# Can I use multiple AWS credentials to read and write with different accounts in Apache-Beam?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-beam

I'm writing a pipeline with Apache Beam that reads from a S3 bucket, transforms it, and writes to a different S3 bucket. The IAM role/account I'm using to read does not have access to the bucket I need to write to. Ideally one account has access to both places I need to access but permissions are locked down unfortunately.

I've tried changing credentials provider between steps but that just changes the credentials provider for the whole pipeline because I haven't actually called `run` yet.

```java
  public static void main(String... args) {

    CustomerOfflineDataOptions options =
        PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(CustomOptions.class);
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(
        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("cred1", "cred1Secret")));

    String inputFileName = "S3:bucket1/input.txt";
    String outputFileName = "S3:bucket1/output.txt";

    PCollection<String> input =
        pipeline
            .apply("ReadInput", TextIO.read().from(inputFileName))
            .apply("Transform", ParDo.of(new TransoformFn()));

    options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(
        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("cred2", "cred2Secret")));

    input.apply("WriteOutput", TextIO.write().to(outputFileName));
    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
  }
```

The options I use extend `AwsOptions`.

```
public interface CustomerOfflineDataOptions extends PipelineOptions, AwsOptions {
  String getInputFile();
  void setInputFile(String file);
}
```

I want to be able specify which credentials to be used for the read and which to be used for the write. Is there an already implemented way to do this? If not, what is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try using [AWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.html)?  
`options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("cred1", "cred1Secret")), new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("cred2", "cred2Secret"))));`

Comment: @OriDar I've given that a try and I'm getting Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'awsCredentialsProvider' with value 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain@5e840abf'. A provider chain almost sounds like something I want, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.